# Andoird P - How to join mp4 files splitted by the camera

Tags: camera, video-recording, mp4, 9.0-pie

I've done multiples videos larger than 4GB with my Pixel 2XL installed with Android P. The camera as splitted my video in 2 files from continuous shooting. In all cases, the first file is readable but, for the second, I can only see the lenght of the video:

[image: splitted files in my phone]

Is there a way or a tool to join these files or to repair the second one ?

I've already try a binary copy with "copy \b" and "cat", a join with `ffmpeg -f concat` and an append with `avidemux` without success.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402650

Comment: It doesn't work because the file system used by android don't support files larger than 4GB

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to recover my video using "[recover_mp4](http://slydiman.me/eng/mmedia/recover_mp4.htm)". I lost a bit sound quality, but at least my video is readable.

Morevoer, I've opened a bug report and this trouble should be fixed for the next release. (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80199853)